# How to use k6 in Node JS

Tags: node.js, k6

I need to send requests using k6 from node js script

I have already tried this:

```
import http from "k6/http";
```

and this:

```
var http = require('k6/http')
```

but it didn't work out

**UPD**

I want to use k6 some like this: 
 node js script:

```
var http = require('k6/http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.get("http://test.loadimpact.com/");
```

Comment: For future readers, you're supposed to run `k6 run script.js` :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot use `k6/http` or any other `k6/*` modules in node.js, or anywhere else besides k6. Those modules are **not** written in JavaScript, they are [written in Go](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/tree/master/js/modules/k6) and are internal for k6 - part of (i.e. compiled in) the k6 binary. They are only accessible from scripts that are ran via k6's JavaScript runtime, which is [goja](https://github.com/dop251/goja), not node.js.

Comment: got it, so can I use some k6 template script( for ex. send post request),  start process from node js  and pass custom params to k6 template script?
in other words, I mean some like this:
`import http from "k6/http";

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('k6', ['run','script.js'], {
    detached: false
});`

Comment: You can launch a k6 process from inside of a node.js script, yes. But that `import http from "k6/http";` in your example is still impossible.

And you cannot use node.js system modules inside of k6 for the same reason you cannot use `k6/*` modules in node.js scripts.